# Java/VScode- .Class Files Not Being Sent to Output Directory

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for my IDE for Java. I have the Setting.json file configured to output my .class files to a directory called 'build':

```
"java.project.outputPath": "build"
```

My Project Folder/File Layout is as follows:

```
math
   \src
       Main.java
       \lib
           Math.java
   \build  <- This is where I want my .class files to be built keeping the same file structure as 
              in the src folder.
```

When I use

```
javac src\Main.java
```

The compiler writes the .class files in the .\src directory, but I'm telling it to write the output in the .\build directory. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: You're using javac directly, so it doesn't use anything configured through VS Code. If you want to specify a build output directory with javac, you need to use the `-d <path>` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I was using the Command Line. VSCode only builds to the specified build path if the build command is run through the gui.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see `settings.json` in the workspace directory structure you provided. I think this may be the cause of the problem.

> "java.project.outputPath"

This setting only takes effect in the workspace scope.

You can create a folder named **.vscode** in your workspace, then create `settings.json`:

[image]

Add the codes in workspace settings.json: `"java.project.outputPath": "build"`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the problem. I was using the Command Line. VSCode only builds to the specified build path if the build command is run through the gui.